# RadioButtonList inside gridview - Server side code too slow, can I do it on the client?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got a radio button list inside a grid view like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLineItems" runat="server">
<asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ToolTip="Please provide an answer to the method." AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ID="rbAnswer" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AnswerID")%>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbAnswer_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" style="color:green;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No" style="color:red;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" Value="N/A" style="color:gray;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display: none" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Currently when you change the selection of the radio button it calls `rbAnswer_SelectedIndexChanged()` in code behind...

The code behind this (and I will shorten it), is something to the effect of:

```
 protected void rbAnswer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((DataControlFieldCell)((RadioButtonList)sender).Parent).Parent;
            RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)gr.FindControl("rbAnswer");

            //since the answer changed set some hidden fields as being changed...
            HtmlInputHidden hiddenFieldAnswered = (HtmlInputHidden)gr.FindControl("hdnAnswered");
            hiddenFieldAnswered.Value = "1";
            HtmlInputHidden hiddenField = (HtmlInputHidden)gr.FindControl("hdnIsChanged");
            hiddenField.Value = "1";

            Panel p;
            p = (Panel)gr.FindControl("pnlAnswer");

            switch (rbl.SelectedItem.Text)
            {
                case "No":
                    gr.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    p.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "Yes":
                    gr.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    p.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case "N/A":
                    gr.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                    p.Visible = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    gr.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                    p.Visible = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Basically if you select an answer it changes the color of a cell in the gridview and it either hides or unhides a panel.  Doing this as back end code causes a big delay in the application.  Can I do this in jquery?  If so how do I access the radiobuttonlist, the answer, the panel, and a way to change the color of the first cell (`gr.cells[0].backcolor`) in jquery?

If I do this all on the client side it may increase the usability for the end users, they are complaining right now it is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. attach click event on radio buttons. I dint test this function, but might it will help you. use jquery file version 1.7 or later

In MarkUp File : Provide a `RowStyle-CssClass` attribute in `GridView`  like

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLineItems" runat="server" RowStyle-CssClass="row">
```

this will help you to find the parent row.

```
$(function(){

     var gvLineItemsRadioObjs = $('[id$=gvLineItems] input[type=radio]');
     gvLineItemsRadioObjs.on('click', function(){

         var $this = $(this);

         //var parentRow =  $this.parents('tr'); // find the parent row.
         var parentRow =  $this.parents('tr.row'); // find the parent row.

         var firstCell = parentRow.find('td:eq(0)'); //find the first cell

         var p =parentRow .find('[id$=pnlAnswer]'); // find the panel

         switch($this.val()) //check the value
         {
            case 'No':
               firstCell.css('background-color', 'red');
               p.show();
               break;
            case 'Yes':
               firstCell.css('background-color', 'green');
               p.hide();
               break;
            case 'N/A':
               firstCell.css('background-color', '');
               p.hide();
               break;
            default:
               firstCell.css('background-color', 'red');
               p.show();
               break;
         }   

    });
});
```

Comment: Nice so far the issue i have is parents() is returning multiple tr's.  For instance, the radiobuttonlist renders as tr and td's so it colors the background of the first radio button.  I need to just color the first column of the grid view...

Comment: @oJM86o Please check the updates. provide a `RowStyle-CssClass` attribute in `GridView` like and access the parent row like `var parentRow =  $this.parents('tr.row');`

Answer (score 0):

Doing a postback whenever a user click a radio button is frustrating to users.

You can do something like this in jQuery

```
$("#tableName").click(function (e) {
if(e.target.nodeName == "INPUT") {
    var radio = $(e.target);
    // Change to whatever element you want to change color
    var chgColor = radio.parent().find(":eq(0)");
    var pnlAnswer = $("#tableName #pnlAnswer");

    switch(radio.val()) {
        case "NO":
            tr.css("background-color": "#FF0000");
            pnlAnswer.show();
            break;
        case "YES":
            tr.css("background-color": "#00FF00");
            pnlAnswer.hide();
            break;  
        // ...
    }
}
```

});

You need to examine the html code that your page generates then figure out how you can manipulate it using jQuery.